# How to improve performance for radialsymmetric integration in matlab

Tags: performance, matlab, image-processing

I have written a code for the following task:

- input: squared image of size e.g. 2001x2001 pixels -> barycenter is at 1001/1001

Starting from the center with an increment of dr = 1pixel I want to know the following characteristics from my image:

- number of points in the radius range (from r to r+dr)
- gray value of this pixels in this range
- ...

Therefore I search the matrix indices for each radius range using the find function in Matlab. Here is my code:

```
s = size(input image);

R = zeros(s(1),s(1));           %Initializing matrix R
x0 = ceil(s(1)/2); y0 = x0;

for i=1:s(1)                    %Calculation of matrix R
        for j=1:s(2)
            R(i,j) = sqrt((x0-j)^2 + (y0-i)^2);
        end       
end

r = 0;                                      %Start of radius at 0
maxr = ceil(max(max(R)));                   %Maximum radius

R2 = gpuArray(R);                           %Move matrix R to GPU

while (r <= (maxr-dr))       
    N = 1*((R2>=r) & (R2<(r+dr)));          %Logical matrix with 1 if r is in the radius range
    indnew = find(N);                       %Find the indices of non-zero elements
    indices = vertcat(indices,indnew);      %Create large vector with the founded indices
    indices = vertcat(indices,(-1));        %Append stop-sign -1
    r = r + dr;
end

ind2 = int32(gather(indices));              %Get indices from GPU to CPU
```

What does this code do:
In this line

> N = 1*((R2>=r) & (R2<(r+dr)));

I get a logical matrix as answer multiplicating this with 1. The matrix has a 1 if r is in the radius range. Then I search the indices of the matrix using the find function. But for an image size of 2000x2000 pixels I need like 30 seconds (using gpuArray(R)) and like one minute without moving R to the GPU.

So it seems that the find function is very slow, but I don´t know a solution which is as stable as the code I have written.

Does anyone has a idea how to find the desired matrix indices in a more elegant and faster way???

Keep in mind that I have at the moment like 1400 loop runs in the while loop. Is it even possible to get the indices faster as with the find function?

Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently did exactly this computation.  The key is to avoid find.  You don't need it, use logical addressing...

```
valsForRanger = inputImage((R>=r) & (R<(r+dr));
numValsForRanger = numel(valsForRanger);
```

You haven't told us what you want the indexes for, but presumably you want to accumulate them in some way.  In that case, [accumarray](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html?refresh=true) is orders of magnitude faster:

```
resultsForEachRingOfSizedr = accumarray(1+round(R(:)/dr),inputImage(:),[],@myAccumFunction);
```

ps. Note, GPU is a red herring here.  I wouldn't use it.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps using a histogram like approach would help. (histcounts)
Bin the elements of R2 into bins from [0:dr:maxr]